# Load initial webview every time tabbar is pressed

Tags: objective-c, webview, delegates, tabview

## Edited

My initial webview is loaded when a tabbar is pressed, then when clicked on the webview, I called
`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` 
to detect the URLString clicked

When the string matches my destination string, I will call the segue `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewsDet" sender:self];` and also pass the URLString and load the detail page on another `ViewController`

Now, when I click the another tabbar and then click back to this tabbar. The detail page remains. I want to refresh back to initial page. How do I do so?

Is it the I need to create a new class with a subclass of `tabviewcontroller`? Please help.

Gym.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
sURL = appDelegate.gURL;
sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/gym.asp"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];

}

- (void)handleRefresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[refresh endRefreshing];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
sURL = appDelegate.gURL;
sURL = [sURL stringByAppendingString:@"/apps/gym.asp"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
 
 }
```

GymDet.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
sURL = self.urlString;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

[image: StoryBoard]

Basically I have 5 tab controllers. Each Tab has a Navigation Controller. When I click on say Tab-A it will load initial `webview` in VC1 then when I click on `webview URL`, it will navigate to a new VC say VC2 and load  the detailed page.
Now, if I click on say Tab-B and back to Tab-A. I want it to load the initial `webview` or VC1. Now, my program always stay at VC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification on what you're trying to do...

Your issue has nothing to do with webviews or loading URLs. The problem is that you are navigating to a new VC in your NavigationController, then switching tabs, then switching back and you are still at the "pushed" VC.

> A comment not related to the problem:
>
> I am on Tab-A, viewing VC-A1... Via "normal" Navigation Controller
>   action, VC-A2 slides-in from the right. Now I select Tab-B, and I see
>   VC-B1. Now, I want to switch back to Tab-A, and I expect to see what
>   was there: VC-A2... but instead, you want to send me back to VC-A1. That really doesn't follow Apple's interface guidelines, and can be very confusing to your users.

However, to accomplish that, you want to subclass `UITabBarController` and implement `didSelectViewController`:

```
#import "MyTabBarViewController.h"

@interface MyTabBarViewController () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyTabBarViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}

@end
```

That will work, but it will "reset" any Navigation Controller in every tab. You'd need to add some other logic to handle *only* the first tab.

---

*(original answer)*

<s>`viewDidLoad` is only called once - when the view loads. Switching between tabs does not "re-load" the view.</s>

You probably want to reload your original URL in `viewWillAppear` as that will be called each time you switch back to that tab.

Although, you probably also want to check if the original URL is the current one displayed - you likely only want to reload it if it's not.

And... you **never** want to call `[self viewWillAppear:YES];` -- that is a notification provided by the system.

Comment: Hi DonMag, I added the above code? Still not working, may I know what I have done wrong? Please help.

Comment: Hmmm... I may have misunderstood what you're doing... In "Tab-A", you have a web view... Are you navigating to "detail page" *within* that web view? As in, tapping a hyperlink and a new page loads? Or, do you have a NavigationController in Tab-A, and you're navigating to a new *view controller* in Tab-A? Then selecting Tab-B, and selecting Tab-A again you need to pop back a step in your Nav Controller (as opposed to simply reloading the current web view)?

Comment: Hi DonMag, sorry I didn't explain cleary. Now I have included my a pic of my storyboard and put some explanation. Hopefully you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Don Mag.